# How do I minimize loop in my xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file.

```
<wd:reporting_data xmlns:wd="com.sri.job">
  <wd:entry>
    <wd:referenceID>ACCTG</wd:referenceID>
    <wd:Job_Name>Accounting</wd:Job_Name>   
  </wd:entry>
  <wd:entry>
    <wd:referenceID>ACTMGT</wd:referenceID>
    <wd:Job_Name>Account Management</wd:Job_Name>  
  </wd:entry>
  <wd:entry>
    <wd:referenceID>ADMIN</wd:referenceID>
    <wd:Job_Name>Administration</wd:Job_Name>  
  </wd:entry>
</wd:reporting_data>
```

I want to print referrenceid in first line and in the next line I want to print all the job names. For that I have written two loops. But I want to use single loop for both the iteration and both the two different kind of data should be in the order of first and second line.

This is my xsl

```
<xsl:variable name="JobFamily">JOB_FAMILY</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ReferrenceId">REFERENCE_ID</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Delimiter">|</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/wd:reporting_data">
    <xsl:value-of select="$ReferrenceId"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:referenceID"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$JobFamily"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Name"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the result what I am trying to get.

```
REFERENCE_ID|ACCTG|ACTMGT|ADMIN|ALPTNR|AUDIT|BIZDEV|BRAND|CCMET|CCMGT|CCOPS|COMPLY|CONTNT|DBMGT|DEV|EMKTG|EXTRPT|FINOPS|FPA|FRAUD|FRDEV|GENMGT|GGRPHY|HOTEL|HRBP|HROPS|HTLPOP|INTCOM|INVREL|ITMGMT|
JOB_FAMILY|Accounting|Account Management|Administration|Alliance/Partnership|Audit|Business Development|Brand|Contact Center Metrics|Contact Center Management|Contact Center Operations|Compliance|
```

Comment: Could you post the exact result yo are trying to get? -- P.S. Please don't post partial code: your XSLT uses two variables that are defined elsewhere - thus it is useless to anyone who wants to try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated my code. Please check it now.

Comment: @ramakrishnanmoorthy please post the result you are trying to achieve and the version of XSLT you are using.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I have updated my question. please check it now.

Comment: I meant show us the result of transforming the given example.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes. I have posted the result of transformation.

Comment: @ramakrishnanmoorthy You result shows data that isn't in your input, for example: `ALPTNR` and `Alliance/Partnership`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k If i mention everything then it will occupy more area. Thats why i mentioned smaller one. I did n't include everything. Just I want to know how do i print both the values in separate line and without using two for loops.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the simplest method to produce the result that (I think) you want is to call `xsl:for-each` twice, the way you have done (or do essentially the same thing by applying templates to `<wd:entry>` twice, using two templates with different modes).

The alternative would be to use a recursive named template, with two accumulating parameters. This is more difficult to set up, and I can't see any tangible advantage this added complication would bring in return.